# How many double letter mutations are possible in a certain DNA string?

Tags: permutations

We are currently doing permutations and factorials in my Maths course. In this week's online quiz there's a question that goes like this:

> A DNA sequence can be represented as a string of the letters ACTG. Given a DNA sequence of length 26, how many double letter mutations are possible?

I have absolutely no background in Chemistry or Genetics so I think I'm interpreting the question incorrectly. Here's what I've tried:

- Picking two random positions and changing each of them: `26*3*25*3`
- Picking two adjacent positions and changing each of them: `25*3*1*3`

All my attempts have been marked as incorrect by the auto-marker. Any ideas?

Comment: Define 'double letter mutations' please

Comment: @KarnWatcharasupat yes that's exactly the problem. The quoted text is all information I'm given.

Comment: Does it actually mean only two of the letters are used?

Comment: Picking two random positions is $(26)(25)/2$, not $(26)(25)$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Bingo! Submit an answer and I'll mark it correct. I apologise to the rest of the community for wasting your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Picking two random positions is ${26\times25\over2}$, not $26\times25$, so the answer they want is $${26\times25\over2}\times3\times3$$

Answer (score -1):

If double-letter mutation means only 2 of the 4 letters are used, then

- choose 2 letters: $\binom42$
- choose the $i$ slots that would be filled by the 'first' letter: $\binom{26}{i}$, $1\le i \le 25$
- sum through all possible $i$'s.

Number of mutations is
$$\binom42\sum_{i=1}^{25}\binom{26}{i}=6\cdot67,108,862=402,653,172$$

Comment: Unfortunately not the correct answer.